# Which api should I use to get location based information about places for iOS app?

Tags: api, iphone-app, geocoding

Should I use Google's Places API or Tripadvisor for points of interests? Apparently TripAdvisor does not allow combining their results with another source.

Which of those (or others) is free and would allow me to avoid quotas? If multiple app users need information about places nearby and the quota is reached I do not want the api calls to be rejected. Also if you have a recommendation for ratings that can be combined with other sources that could also be good.

Is downloading all of the points of interest for a country in advance and storing them locally a viable option ?

Thank you for any recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Places API is one of the best i know. It is the most accurate one and it is also free but ou only have limits requests per day for the API. If you are launching an app then you should purchase an Google Places API plan so it will be ot easier for you. There is no open and this accurate api available for places.

Downloading and storing all points is not a vaiable option bacause it will require a storage facility i.e. a database and a custom REST API backend to serve the data.

Also It will create a need of server hosting.